# Cross project push pub sub and firewall rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a project, call it `Project A`. I have created a subscription to a Pub/Sub topic owned by `Project B`. This subscription is configured to deliver push notifications to my endpoint. I would like to create some firewall rules to restrict access to the instances handling the pub/sub notifications so that only Google can access the instances when delivering the notifications. I don't want any other inbound traffic to the hosts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.  From 
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#pubsub-pull-messages-csharp

> Currently the only supported endpoint is an HTTPS server that can
>   accept Webhook delivery. Note that the HTTPS URL for the Webhook **must**
>   **be accessible from the public web**. The receiving endpoint may be
>   decoupled from the Pub/Sub subscription; so messages from multiple
>   subscriptions may be sent to a single endpoint.

To answer the larger question which may be relevant to you:

*How do I prevent attackers from posting bogus messages to my endpoint?*

The answer to that question is to share a secret between Project A and Project B, and include an artifact of that secret in the message attributes.  Sign the message with a private key and include the signature in the attributes.  Then, the endpoint receives the message and verifies the signature against a public key.

Comment: Project B creates a public/private key pair and only shares its public key.  Then the key does not need to be kept secure.